# Pass Model to bootstrap

Tags: c#, jquery

In my project I have Class A, which has collection of class B.
Something like this:

```cs
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I'm iterating through A elements and do a div's list.
Now, when I'm clicking some div, I want to pass B elements to modal and show some values there.
Something like:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<A>

@foreach (var a in A)
{
    <div class="container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal" <!-- how to pass this model here and use it in Modal?--> >
        <p>@a.Name</p>
     </div>
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as json like:

```
@foreach (var a in A)
{
    <div class="container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal"
      data-value='@JsonConvert.Serialize(a.B)'>
        <p>@a.Name</p>
     </div>
}
```

then you can just read the json like:

```
var model = JSON.parse($('.container').data('value'));
```

Comment: great thanks, I had to use JSON.stringify also ```var model = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($(this).data('id-model')));```, but now how can I use this model in modal?

Comment: If you check my answer, you can get the model by parsing json, and you can access it like  `for(var i=0;i<model.length;i++) ` .... and now you have `model[i].id`, `model[i].name`, `model[i].isValid`